# Correlation of Indicator Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, correlation

Show that for indicator random variables $I_A$ and $I_B$ of Events $A$ and $B$:

$Corr(I_A, I_B) = Corr(I_A^c, I_B^c) = -Corr(I_A, I_B^c) = -Corr(I_A^c, I_B)$

Deduce that if $A$ and $B$ are positively dependent, then so are $A^c$ and $B^c$, but $A$ and $B^c$ are negatively dependent, as are $A^c$ and $B$.

Not sure how to show this.

Comment: Show what you did. If you know how correlation is defined, you have to have tried something.

Comment: I tried making IA=IB=1 and IAc=IBc=0 and computing this but it doesn't make any sense. I couldn't use the definition of correlation because I don't know the expectations or standard deviations of the random variables.

Comment: *I tried making IA=IB=1 and IAc=IBc=0*... Sorry but I do not understand, $\mathbf 1_A$ is a *random variable*, that is, a *function*, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note a basic rule of indicators, $I_A=1-I_\bar{A}$.

It may also help to refer to problem 6.4.16 where it asks to prove that
$$
Corr(aX+b,cY+d) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
      Corr(X,Y) & \quad \text{if $a$ and $c$ have the same sign} \\
      -Corr(X,Y) & \quad \text{if $a$ and $c$ have opposite signs}
   \end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: what is $I_\bar{A}$?

Comment: nevermind I got it, thanks.